# Traverse a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

Is it possible to navigate through an object in JavaScript, referencing one 'area'/section of the object in another?

For example, if I have an object which is structured like below:

```
var config = {
    resources: {
        styles: 'path/to/a/stylesheet',
        scripts: 'path/to/a/javascript/file'
    },
    options: {
        plugin_a: {
            entries: [config.resources.styles, config.resources.scripts]
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible for me to, for example, reference the path to my styles and scripts files in 'config.resources.styles' and 'config.resources.scripts' in the 'config.options.plugin_a' section?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, amended the post.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket in your `resources`, and you could indeed do this with getters: `options: { plugin_a : { get styles: function(){ return config.resources.styles; }}}`.

Comment: Whoops! Nice spot, @somethinghere, I've added the missing bracket in!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two separate lines: create the config object, then set config.options to the object using config values.
Instead of `var a={b:1,c:a.b}` use `var a={b:1}; a.c=a.b;`